# decoration the title of section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, pdftex

[image]

I want to add a line segment of about 3 cm that follows the title of section in my book. How can you modify the following code?  I add `\rule{3cm}{.45pt}` in but it notices capacity exceeds.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancybox} 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage[textwidth=16.25cm,textheight=19cm]{geometry} %kho sach 18x23

\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{graphics, graphpap}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}

\pagebreak
\section{Perimeter {\rule{3cm}{.45pt}} }

\begin{enumerate} 
\item first item
\item second item

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your rule will appear in the ToC, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without any packages: Make a quick and dirty redefinition of `\@sect`, the underlying macro for the `\section` etc. commands.

The redefinition checks whether section or another `subsection` etc is used and then applies the `\rule`.

Change the `\ruledistskip` length at will...

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancybox} 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage[textwidth=16.25cm,textheight=19cm]{geometry} %kho sach 18x23

\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{graphics, graphpap}

\newlength\ruledistskip
\setlength{\ruledistskip}{5em}

\makeatletter
\let\l@tex@sect\@sect
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \l@tex@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[#7]{#8\ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{section}%
    \hskip\ruledistskip\rule{3cm}{.45pt}%
    \fi}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}

\clearpage
\section{Perimeter}

\subsection{Ruleless}

\begin{enumerate} 
\item first item
\item second item

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have added a picture to describe better what it should look like: the segment is in the same horizontal line with the title.

Comment: @Thumbolt: Why do you not write this right from the start?

Comment: Because I thought \section{Perimeter {\rule{3cm}{.45pt}} } describes enough what it is.

Comment: @Thumbolt: That would be quite ugly, since it leaves the rule in the ToC as well ;-)

Comment: In fact, I use \section*{ab} then it should not be in the toc.